# java constant against bytecode reverse engineering

Tags: java, string, encryption, reverse-engineering, bytecode

I would like to know if I can encrypt a string inside a compiled java file.
For example, i need to decode a zip file with symmetric key and I need to store that key in a java class in a private constant:

```
private static final String ZIP_PASSW="secret"
```

But i don't want that a simple reversing bytecode shows the raw password... Do you think exists something to avoid it?

Thank you

PS: I can not understand why S.O. said that my question does not meet its standards without this PS

Comment: I think its a good question and in some cases asynchonous crypto (as everyone is screaming out that buzzword here) won't help you that much with that problem. E.g. when you want to store a user specified password in your applications database that you need to be able to retrieve in cleartext but you dont want to store it in cleartext in the db. So your application must be able to encrypt AND decrypt it => you will have the same problem of a key (respectively two keys for asynch encryption) that you'll have to provide. No matter if you use something synchrone as AES or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say you need to decode a zip file with a symmetric key, is that *definitely* what you need to do? Rather than thinking about the detail of how to store the password as plaintext or how to encode it or whatever, you might need to look at your overall architecture. For example perhaps your code could call a secured webservice to get the key rather than storing it? Obviously, without a better picture of what you are aiming for it is hard to suggest a viable alternative, but what you are describing is going to be hard to keep properly secure - it will be secure by obscurity, but it won't be strong against someone determined to find your key.

If that isn't secure enough for what you need to do, then the most standard response would probably to integrate some kind of PGP key exchange rather than using symmetric encryption.

Comment: I have to create a DB dump file to let the user backup all data in external memory. But i don't want a plain file...

Comment: Howsabout your user uploads a public key, then you can encrypt the data but you can't decrypt it without the private key. They download it encrypted and can decrypt it at their leisure.

Comment: I can not understand why asiymetric keys can solve my problem... I still need to store the private key inside my code or am I wrong?

Comment: Asymetric keys only need the private key to decrypt, so you can encrypt if you have the public key but not decrypt. Obviously requires a savvy user or a client of some kind that manages decryption, but you never store the private key- only the public one.

Answer (score 4):

A real hacker will still be able to decrypt the password, but you could make it a bit harder if you don't store the password as a String literal. You could use:

```
private static final String KEY = new String(new char[]{'s', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't'});
```

This will result in the byte codes:

```
javap -c -v TestObfuscate

static {};
  Code:
   Stack=6, Locals=0, Args_size=0
   0:   new #10; //class java/lang/String
   3:   dup
   4:   bipush  6
   6:   newarray char
   8:   dup
   9:   iconst_0
   10:  bipush  115
   12:  castore
   13:  dup
   14:  iconst_1
   15:  bipush  101
   17:  castore
   18:  dup
   19:  iconst_2
   20:  bipush  99
   22:  castore
   23:  dup
   24:  iconst_3
   25:  bipush  114
   27:  castore
   28:  dup
   29:  iconst_4
   30:  bipush  101
   32:  castore
   33:  dup
   34:  iconst_5
   35:  bipush  116
   37:  castore
   38:  invokespecial   #12; //Method java/lang/String."<init>":([C)V
   41:  putstatic   #16; //Field KEY:Ljava/lang/String;
   44:  return
```

whereas

```
private static final String ZIP_PASSW="secret"
```

returns

```
Constant pool:
const #8 = String   #9; //  secret
```

Please note I didn't call the constant `PASSWORD` or `ZIP_PASSW` (this is important if the string is public).

As an alternative or in addition to that, you could use an obfuscation tool such as [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: a public string is not very good idea :-) I like this solution... :-) i know that is not very secure, but is something better than nothing

Comment: jad would still decompile it into this: `private static final String KEY = new String(new char[] { 's', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't'});`

Comment: for most decompilers this will not help as maksimov already said

Comment: what about simple arithmetic (rot13, xor with something etc.) to guard the key against the first view?

Answer (score 3):

If you store the key in your code it can always be retrieved by reverse engineering. Also it doesn't matter if you store the key before or after compiling.

There is no way you can deliver any sort of (unencrypted) key with your program without the possibility to reverse-engineer it. That is why asymmetric encryption was invented in first place.

So if you insist on using symmetric encryption, you have to store the key outside of your application (for example in a text file) and deliver the file on a secure channel to the users of your program. (Who of course can use the key any way they want).

If that is not what you want you should look into asymmetric encryption techniques.

Answer (score 1):

The best you could do is to make it a bit more difficult to access. Any encrypted string could be decrypted using the password stored in the code. You could take measures to hide the password, but using private constants is not one of such measures.

Answer (score 0):

How about to store already encrypted password?

Answer (score 0):

No, if you store an encrypted password you'll still have to decrypt it at some point and a cracker can just disassemble your code and figure out the algorithm, and get from that the password.